# arithmetic operation on text file column

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have four columns in my text file. I need to take average value of fourth column corresponding to second column and save output in another file which will contain only two columns with average results. Kindly help

```
ABC DEF IGK LMN
21  56700   001000  -98.3
24  56700   002000  -96.3
6   56700   003000  -93.8
9   56700   004000  -47.3
21  56700   005000  -58.3
36  56700   006000  -78.3
21  56701   001000  -98.3
28  56701   002000  -98.3
21  56701   003000  -99.3
20  56701   004000  -58.3
21  56701   005000  -99.3
10  56701   006000  -98.3
2   56701   007000  -87.3
2   56701   008000  -57.3
21  56702   001000  -63.3
1   56702   002000  -67.3
17  56702   003000  -47.3
21  56702   004000  -73.3
13  56702   005000  -60.3
10  56702   006000  -90.3
14  56702   007000  -77.3
11  56702   008000  -97.3
10  56702   009000  -98.3
13  56702   010000  -87.3
17  56702   011000  -77.3
11  56702   012000  -68.3
```

Expected output:

```
DEF Average of LMN
56700   -78.71666667
56701   -87.05
56702   -75.63333333
```

I can get the overall average of 4th column in one go by using:

```
awk '{total+= $4} END {print total/NR}' inputfilename.txt
```

but I need to apply a condition.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i am getting whole column average in one go by using :////// awk '{total+= $4} END {print total/NR}' inputfilename.txt  ////////     but i need to apply condition.

Comment: What is the expected output for the given input?

Comment: if the input is fixed length (all keys on byte 5..10) you can extract these keys with cut and do a while-loop with grep for each key.

Comment: it not fixed some times it logs every second data so data is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Use two arrays, one for sums; one for counting how many numbers added to them. At the end of file print `DEF`s and corresponding averages.

```
awk 'NR>1{count[$2]++;total[$2]+=$4} END{for(key in count) print key, total[key]/count[key]}' file
```

<sub>**Note:** `NR>1` is for excluding header line, if actual input doesn't have a header line simply drop it.</sub>

Given your sample its output looks like:

```
56700 -74.8
56701 -87.05
56702 -75.6333
```

Then you can sort the output using `sort` if it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you explain the syntax please.

Comment: @preeti Read [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) instead. Because there is no syntactic trick in above command, everything is straightforward

Comment: Thanks @ismail will do that. i am a beginer and wanted to process my data.

Comment: @preeti that's whole another question. and I don't know anything about plotting

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using a more powerful language, specially when you need to do more fancy stuff.

E.g. `python`

```
DEF_map = {}
with open('in.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines()[1:]:
        s = line.split()
        if s[1] not in DEF_map:
            DEF_map[s[1]] = []
        DEF_map[s[1]].append(float(s[3]))

print("DEF Average of LMN")
for DEF, LMN_list in DEF_map.items():
    print("{}\t{}".format(DEF, sum(LMN_list)/len(LMN_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

because your original tags include bash, here is an example with `bash` and the `bc`-tool (not an one-line code, but sometimes hopeful to learn bash):

```
# only if needed in a short variable, later possible to test if exist, readable, ...
in=/path/to/your/testfile.txt
# we build a loop over your keys, possible
#  - for fixed length files and a fixed byte position
#    cut -b 5-10 
#  - for variable blocked with one (ore more) spaces as delimiter
#    sed -e 's/  */ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2   
for key in $(cat $in | cut -b 5-10 | sort -u) ; do
  # initialize counter for summary and number of elements per key
  s=0; a=0
  # grep all your relevant data from your inputfile (only for the key)
  # depends on your data you can grep on bytes (here from start of line with 4
  # characters and from byte 5-10 with your key)
  for x in $(grep -E "^.{4}${key}" $in | sed -e 's/  */ /g' | cut -d' ' -f4) ; do
    # count sum and add 1 to the number of entries
    s=$(echo "$s+$x" | bc --mathlib)
    ((a++))
  done
  # now print your key (as integer) and avg (as float with 6 decimals)
  printf "%i %.6f\n" $key $(echo "$s/$a" | bc --mathlib)
done
```

`bc` used with parameter `--mathlib` use a scale of 20. If needed or you want it, you can use a higher scale and reduce the decimals only at printing the result.

This solution with two loops (one for the keys and the other per key) is only acceptable if your linenumbers of the inputfile are not to large (I don't use this example for million of lines), but it's more readable as some one-line code (especially for beginners).